# after using as.Date(x) - as.Date(y) there are "days" after the number

Tags: r

Hopefully this is a simple question:

I'm creating a column in my data_frame that takes the date fifference of two date columns.

I get the correct result but when I call on this data frame again, in this new column, I get "days" written after the number.

```
 my code is:

 temp <- temp %>%
 mutate(AGEMOS = as.numeric(as.Date(temp$INTERVIEWDATE,"%m/%d/%Y")-
                 as.Date(temp$BDAY,"%m/%d/%Y")) / 30.475)
```

and, to re-iterate, AGEMOS now has "days written after each numeric value.

Is there any way to get rid of this or change it to Years?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `as.numeric` with parameter `units`:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("2017-08-20")-as.Date("2017-09-03"), units = "days")
```

Answer (score 2):

To understand the behavior, you need to recognize that subtracting two dates does not return a numeric vector.  It returns a vector of class `difftime`

```
x <- as.Date("2017-05-11")
y <- as.Date("2017-01-23")

z <- x - y 

class(x) # Date
class(y) # Date
class(z) # difftime
```

The `difftime` object has its own `print` method that prints the `units` attribute for clarity. This can generate confusion because subsequent operations don't can change the units, but the `units` attribute of the `difftime` object won't change.

```
z / 30
Time difference of 3.6 days
```

I recommend a slightly safer approach to calculating time differences

```
as.numeric(difftime(x, y, units = "days"))
```

I actually do recommend specifying the `units` argument; depending on how close the objects are, the auto selection of the units in R may not always be the same (this is more likely to be true with `POSIXct` variables, which are date/time objects.  By specifying the units you want to work with, you can avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `difftime` and specify the units you are interested in. i.e. `difftime(temp$BDAY, temp$INTERVIEWDATE, units = "days"` as long as they parameters are a `date` class.